# O que é Port Knocking?

Tags: linux, ssh

Pelo que percebi trata-se de enviar uma sequência de pedidos a um servidor de modo a desbloquear um porto.

Seria então possível através de um browser ativar o porto para ssh, por exemplo:

Aceder a `servidor.com:80` depois a `servidor:81` e em seguida a `servidor:82` desbloqueado o porto 9999 (ssh) por exemplo?

Achei o conceito interessante, mas nunca tinha ouvido falar. 
É muito utilizado? 
Existem alternativas semelhantes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**O que é Port Knocking?**
Port Knocking é conhecido como o ato de visitar / bater / enviar dados em portas específicas, assim permitindo que uma outra porta seja aberta após a sequência de portas corretas tenham sido visitadas.

**É muito utilizada?**
Não, pois o serviço de Port Knocking introduz ao sistema diversos problemas que não existiriam, causando no final das contas mais desvantagens do que vantagens. Dentre os piores problemas, citarei o [SPOF (Single point of failure - ponto de falha única)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure), o que é um problema já que a maior parte dos serviços são feitos para não possuir esse tipo de falha, o problema da [Segurança por obscurantismo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) que leva a falsa crença de que se o atacante não conhecer o que está atacando terá mais dificuldades (Nota: Apesar de alguns discordarem, eu acredito que é uma forma de obscurantismo), é sendo facilmente reproduzível caso exista o ataque "Man in the Middle" e dependendo do modo de implementação é [equivalente a uma senha plaintext](https://github.com/BuddhaLabs/PacketStorm-Exploits/blob/master/0004-exploits/RFP2K03.txt).

**Alternativas ao Port Knocking**
A principal alternativa *similar* ao port knocking é o [Shimmer](http://shimmer.sourceforge.net/), mantendo sempre 16 portas online em que somente uma é fornece o que se realmente deseja, todas as outras fornecem acesso a um serviço "falso". Essas 16 portas mudam a cada minuto, fazendo assim que um atacante tivesse que adivinhar qual porta é a correta e conseguisse penetra-la antes das portas mudarem novamente. Para uma maior segurança de sincronismo, o minuto anterior e próximo ao atual também é considerado, então são 48 portas - sendo que somente 3 fornecem o serviço correto.

A melhor alternativa ao port knocking é uma simples autenticação em 2 fatores, que fornece uma alternativa real ao problema que é testado e utilizado por várias gigantes da tecnologia.

**Links para Aprofundamento**
http://bsdly.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/why-not-use-port-knocking.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Port_knocking
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/port-knocking-is-it-a-good-idea

Answer (score 1):

A ideia é "bater" nas portas certas e na sequencia correta e para isso tu pode utilizar até mesmo o telnet host:1111; telnet host:2222, telnet host:3333 por exemplo.

Segue alguns artigos úteis:

[Wiki ArchLinux - Port knocking](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Port_knocking)

[How to Secure SSH Server using Port Knocking on Ubuntu Linux](https://komunity.komand.com/learn/article/server-administration/how-to-secure-ssh-server-using-port-knocking-on-ubuntu-linux/)

Espero ter ajudado, abraços!